# how to transfer element from one drop down to another drop down list in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  var opt = options[i];
  var a = document.createElement("option");
  a.textContent = opt;
  a.value = opt;
  select.appendChild(a);
}

function moveright() {
  var selected = document.getElementById(dropdown(options[selectedIndex].value)

  }
```

I don't know the what code I want to write for transfer one drop down lo another can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried, what errors to you get, what exactly were you trying to do? Please be more specific.

Comment: i am trying to transfer numbers from first drop down list to second drop down box i tried but the code was wrong

Comment: [It may helps you](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/list-move.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I didn't understand what do you want, but to copy HTML elements in Javascript you can just use cloneNode. For example:

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var selectedCloned = select.cloneNode(true);
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(selectedCloned);
```

**Edit**

Just do it like this:

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5","6","7","8","9"];
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) 
{
    var opt = options[i];
    var a = document.createElement("option");
    a.textContent = opt;
    a.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(a);
}
var secondDropdown = select.cloneNode(true);
```

your second dropdown will be in secondDropdown variable. And then just append where you want.

Comment: I want to push the first drop down elements into second drop down box

Comment: So who is your first dropdown, your second dropdown and where you want to append your second dropdown?

Comment: This code is creating drop down box. I am just trying to push the 1st box elements into second box

Comment: My first drop down box is numbers from 1 to 9 I want to transfer this numbers into empty drop down box